# how to display date and time separately in grid view

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have one column in SQL table. which name is `Intime`. Its data type is `nvarchar`. It stores both date and time. But I want date and time separately.

I have tried this query:

```
select  AttendanceDate,
        SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,intime,113),1,11)[Intime],
        SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,intime,113),13,19)[InTime],
        InDeviceId,
        OutTime,
        OutTime,
        OutDeviceId, 
        dbo.MinutesToDuration(duration) as Duration,
        Status 
from dbo.AttendanceLogs 
where  EmployeeId=2938 
order by AttendanceDate desc
```

but if I pass same SQL command in grid view its not working.

```
public void Bind()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select AttendanceDate,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,intime,113),1,11) as [InTime],SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,InTime,113),13,19) as [Intime],InDeviceId,OutTime,OutTime,OutDeviceId, dbo.MinutesToDuration(duration) as Duration,Status from dbo.AttendanceLogs where  EmployeeId='" + empIdtxt.Text + "' and year(AttendanceDate)=" + ddlYear.SelectedItem + "  and month(AttendanceDate)=" + ddlmnt.SelectedValue + " order by AttendanceDate desc", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridView1.ControlStyle.Font.Size = 10;

    }
```

Where possibly could be the problem?

Comment: YOUR GRIDVIEW HTML

Comment: please try to give the Aliases different names

Comment: already i tried. but its not working

Comment: debug your code which error are throwing

Comment: Appreciate you may not be able to change the db design but my advice is to always use the [correct data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).  Benefits include improved validation and easier extraction of date/time parts.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
   public void Bind()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select AttendanceDate,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,intime,113),1,11) as [InTimeD],SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,InTime,113),13,19) as [IntimeT],
            InDeviceId,OutTime,OutTime,OutDeviceId, dbo.MinutesToDuration(duration) as Duration,Status from dbo.AttendanceLogs
                where  EmployeeId='" + empIdtxt.Text + "' and year(AttendanceDate)=" + ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value +
                                     "  and month(AttendanceDate)=" + ddlmnt.SelectedValue + " order by AttendanceDate desc", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd,con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            GridView1.ControlStyle.Font.Size = 10;

        }
```

this line not filter any year it return object of drop down list

```
year(AttendanceDate)=" + ddlYear.SelectedItem + "
```

Comment: your gridview should not have custom item

Comment: sorry. its not working. if i give different alias names it will not bind the data..again my out put showing only date in 2 grid view coloumn instead of date and time. and my grid view does not have custom item